# Object assignment in Ruby in the JavaScript way

Tags: ruby, hash, variable-assignment

In JavaScript (ES6), I can write the following as a shortcut for creating a new object with a key and its value sharing the same name:

```
var a = 1
var b = 2

var myobject = { a, b };
```

This is essentially the same as:

```
var myobject = { a: a, b: b };
```

How can I do it for a Ruby hash?

Comment: There have been proposals for a feature to allow that, but at the moment, you cannot do that.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to achieve here, but it sounds a little like OpenStruct.

It takes any method name as an attribute, and any method name followed by an = as a setter...

```
require 'ostruct'
x = OpenStruct.new(a: 'a', b: 'b')

x.a
# 'a'
x.foo
# nil
x.foo = 'bar'
# 'bar'
```